# How enumerate resources inside a resx file programmatically?

Tags: .net, resources

Using Visual Studio 2010

How can I enumerate all resources within in a specific resource file (.resx) that lies inside my assembly?

In my project I have a Resources.resx file with 3 text files (string resource). I need to enumerate these 3 files and then use their names to get their contents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found out:

```
Dim man As New ResourceManager("Discovery.Resources", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly)
Dim resset As ResourceSet
resset = man.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, True, True)
For Each item As DictionaryEntry In resset
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key)
Next
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [ResXResourceReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resxresourcereader.aspx) from `System.Windows.Forms`.

> It Enumerates XML resource (.resx)
>   files and streams, and reads the
>   sequential resource name and value
>   pairs

```
public static void Main()
{

  // Create a ResXResourceReader for the file items.resx.
  ResXResourceReader rsxr = new ResXResourceReader("items.resx");

  // Iterate through the resources and display the contents to the console.
  foreach (DictionaryEntry d in rsxr)
  {
      Console.WriteLine(d.Key.ToString() + ":\t" + d.Value.ToString());
  }

 //Close the reader.
 rsxr.Close();
```

}

Comment: Hi @Andrzej, but how can I do that if the resx file is inside my assembly (generated in visual studio project properties window)?

Comment: @RHaguiuda  Please check here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984408%28VS.71%29.aspx