# In an Office Addin Is it possible to specify image just from ribbon xml?

Tags: ms-word, vsto, office-addins, word-addins, ribbonx

I started by creating xml from the ribbon designer. I already have a resource file containing button images.
I got lines like

```
<button id="btnInsEq2" onAction="BtnInsEq2_Click" showLabel="false" />
```

which I changed to

```
<button id="btnInsEq2" onAction="BtnInsEq2_Click" image="InsEquation2" showImage="true" showLabel="false" />
```

There is some image called InsEquation2 in my resource file, which is accessible at runtime. I tried many variations on "InsEquation2" including the full path of the file. Nothing works.

I see answers where images are loaded in code. Is that really necessary or can I do it simpler in the xml?
By the way a line like

```
<button id="btnInsEq3" onAction="BtnInsEq3_Click" imageMso="Bold"  label=" " showLabel="false" />
```

works fine. But I dont want **B**!

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways for loading images in the Ribbon XML.

1. The `getImage` callback for each element where it is supported.
2. The `loadImages` callback for the `customUI` element where all images are loaded.

So, if you want to specify image names in the ribbon XML markup you need to implement the `loadImages` callback for the `customUI` element.

The `<customUI>` element's `loadImage` attribute enables you to specify a callback that can load all images. After you set up this callback procedure, Office calls the callback procedure and passes the string from the image attribute for each control that loads images. You do not need to implement the `getImage` callback multiple times, such as one time for each control that requires images. For example, a customization might include markup like the following.

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" 
  loadImage="GetImage">
<!-- Later in the markup -->
   <button id="myButton" image="mypic.jpg" />
```

To supply the button's image, Office calls the `GetImage` function. It passes the parameter "mypic.jpg" and expects an `IPictureDisp` object in return. By using this technique, you can write a single callback procedure that returns all the images your customization needs, without having to write each individual control's `getImage` callback. Note that the `loadImage` callback is not called again when you call the Ribbon's Invalidate method or `InvalidateControl` method. For the controls that need to change images dynamically at run time, use the `getImage` callback.

Comment: I don't know what I should put in the GetImage function. Could we have a small sample please? At the moment the best I can do is follow @STHOH's sample but then every image is the same! As expected but not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the getImage tag like:

```
<button id="btnInsEq2" onAction="BtnInsEq2_Click" showLabel="false" getImage="GetImage"/>
```

which requires a callback. Assuming you write in C# it could look something like:

```
public Bitmap GetImage(Office.IRibbonControl control)
{
     return new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.RelevantImage);
}
```

Comment: So are you saying that the image="..." doesn't work? When one types image="" the popup says 
A custom image or icon. A string argument for a path to a file or resource. Is it lying?

Comment: It works. But not all developers know all possible ways of loading images in the Ribbon XML.

Comment: I am definitely not saying it is lying. Just trying to show you a way of solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

So now I have found out what to put in the GetImage function suggested by @EugeneAstafiev . Basically you need to iterate through the resources and find the one indicated by the imageId input parameter. Here it is in XML / VB

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas ... loadImage="GetButtonImages" >
..
  <group id="InsertEquations" label="Add" image="InsEquation">
    <button id="btnInsEq2" onAction="BtnInsEq2_Click" image="InsEquation2"/>

    Public Function GetButtonImages(imageId As String) As Bitmap  'was IPictureDisp as specified in documenation 
        'enumerate resources ...
        'see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656883/how-enumerate-resources-inside-a-resx-file-programmatically
        Dim ErrorBitmap As New Bitmap(My.Resources._Error)
        Dim ResMan As New ResourceManager("EquationAcc.Resources1", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly)
        Dim ResSet As ResourceSet
        ResSet = ResMan.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, True, True)
        For Each Item As DictionaryEntry In ResSet
            'Debug.WriteLine(item.Key)       'appears in window from Debug / windows / output
            If Item.Key = imageId Then
                Return Item.Value
            End If
        Next
        Return ErrorBitmap
    End Function
```

Also needed Imports System.Drawing, .Collections, .Globalization, .Reflection, .Resources
for declarations and
.Diagnostics, stdole for some now unused declarations
EquationAcc is the project, Resources1.resx the resource file

If there is a better way I'd love to know.